# Please resolve the discord is not defined error in the discord.js file

Tags: javascript, windows, discord, discord.js

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
});

const discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () =>{
       console.log("bot on")
})

client.on('message', msg =>{
       if(msg.content === "text"){
              msg.reply("good")
       }
})

client.login("Private token")
```

After inserting the token using that code, I ran it and got the same error as the title.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure you are using the correct import statement for Discord.js library. you have imported the discord.js library and created a new Client instance using the Client constructor.

you have also imported the library again using const discord = require('discord.js') and create another Client instance using new Discord.Client(). This creates a conflict because you're trying to use the Client class from two different imports.

you can remove the unnecessary import statement and use the existing Client instance you create